# Jekyll & Github Pages: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)

Tags: syntax-error, jekyll, github-pages

I am working on a Jekyll project and it builds/serves properly. When I add `github-pages` as a gem, I run bundle update because it needs to resolve dependencies. After doing so, I try to build and/or serve and it returns the following error while generating the static site:

```
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```ruby
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
# gem "jekyll", "~> 3.6.2"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
# gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
  gem "jekyll-assets"
  gem "jekyll-minifier"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Here is the full output when I run build:

```
    $ be jekyll build
Configuration file: /Users/fong/dev/Projects/Portfolio/jekyll_portfolio/portfolio/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/fong/dev/Projects/Portfolio/jekyll_portfolio/portfolio
       Destination: /Users/fong/dev/Projects/Portfolio/jekyll_portfolio/portfolio/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)
```

**Does anyone know why this might be happening?**

I've narrowed in on the `github-pages` gem as a cause for the issue but I'm not sure what the root cause is and how to resolve the problem.

Comment: always use `--trace` option to get more information on errors: `bundle exec jekyll build --trace`

Comment: Great tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `theme: minima` back into my config. This appears to have resolved the build issues.